# "JDK (Java Development Kit) not Installed" when using Visual Studio Code with Titanum

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, titanium, appcelerator

I've seen a few people having this exact error when using titanium extension in VS Code but I have yet to see a definitive solution.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

When I click "Play" to try to run my "hello world" program I see this error:
[original error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkx1g.png)

```
[ERROR] JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.
[ERROR] If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
[ERROR] The JDK is required for Titanium and must be manually downloaded and installed from http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

In environment variables I set java_home by selecting the appropriate folder:

[java_home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChiXI.png)

and set the path to point to the bin directory

[java_home path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWnf3.png)

if I echo java_home it looks right.

[echo java_home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUL0T.png)

**EDIT** 5/19/2020

Current appc info

```
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.18362.  All Rights Reserved.
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 15.9GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 12.16.3
  npm Version                 = 6.14.4

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 5.0.0
  Core Package                = 8.0.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.2.2
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.49

Titanium SDKs
  9.0.1.GA
    Version                   = 9.0.1
    Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\9.0.1.GA
    Platforms                 = android
    git Hash                  = 466c007fd2
    git Timestamp             = 4/15/2020 21:37
    node-appc Version         = 0.3.4

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Installed                   = yes
  Memory Limit                = 0 BYTES

Java Development Kit
  Not found

Genymotion
  Path                        = not found
  Genymotion Executable       = not found
  Genymotion Player           = not found
  Home                        = not found

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = not found
  Version                     = unknown

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = not found
  SDK Path                    = not found

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  None

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None

Genymotion Emulators
  None

Connected Android Devices
Samsung Galaxy S10 (preview)
  ID                          = 192.168.80.101:5555
  State                       = device
  SDK Version                 = 10 (android-29)
  ABIs                        = x86

Java Development Kit Issues
  ×  JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.
     If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly
     set.
     The JDK is required for Titanium and must be manually downloaded and installed from
     http://appcelerator.com/jdk.

Android Issues
  ×  JDK (Java Development Kit) not found.
     If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly
     set.
     The JDK can be downloaded and installed from http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

Comment: Please, don't use links to pictures! Type out the error and add it in a code fence. Do the same for your other images!

Comment: Follow the docs and install the right JDK. You need 1.8.x

Comment: done - same issue

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get this kind of working.  I don't know if any of these is the magic bullet but here is what I did.

1. Deleted all java installations.  Over time various programs had installed their own.
2. Deleted all jdks.
3. Deleted appcelerator and titanium plugin for vs code.  Also deleted the corresponding module folder manually.
4. Rebooted
5. Installed java 8 as per the docs.
6. Installed corresponding jdks  for this version and titanium plugins.
7. I set java_home in windows and java.home in appc.

This is where things got kind of interesting.  It still wasn't working at this point.  I kept messing around with java home and it still wasn't working.  It seemed that it wanted reboots after these changes and that simply closing VS Code wasn't enough.  After one reboot things changed - VS Code picked up that java.home and java home were not in sync (one had "bin" in the path) and the other did not.  When running appc info I could see that all of the sudden more information was being returned that had not been previously.

So I removed "bin" from the path and all of the sudden it was working again (I think I rebooted again).  I was now up and running in the emulator!  For a while, anyway.  I was then getting gradle java heap errors and when I set java options and rebooted and rebooted I lost jdk again.  Anyway.... that's my story.  #$%$%$#%$% titanium.

Comment: I know it is frustrating, but why blaming the SDK if the tools around it (Java, VSCode) are not working :) That's like blaming Google for an error in Whatsapp. You can always try Atom or even use VSCode and compile using a normal terminal next to it. It even might be that it is some user permission problem (e.g. start vscode as admin) or that vscode is messing up the path. Tried my best to help, I find the installation in Linux, OSX and Windows very streamline and it was working out of the box for me.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this working on Ubuntu by removing every jdk installation through synaptic and then installing a jdk using `sudo apt install default-jdk`

Answer (score 1):

Please install JAVA 1.8 (JDK 8)

Comment: Argh!  I completely forgot about that.  Ok, so I updated java_home and then restarted VS Code but I am getting the same error.   "Where Java" returns this:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe

Comment: there are multiple things you can check: `appc info`, `appc ti config android` and try to compile it from command line `appc ti build -p android --build-only`

Comment: One other observation.  I am now seeing the same error in Appcelerator studio.  I had stopped using Appcelerator Studio last week as I had hoped to start using VS Code instead.  I did not have this error last week before I tried to move to VS Code.

Comment: This has turned in to an absolute nightmare ever since I tried to transition to VS Code with the titanium plugin.  Now both appcelerator client and VS Code have the exact same error.  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and lots of other things.  This is not my area of expertise - I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that I could get.

Comment: I have to go through the windows setup again (using linux here) but the JDK part should be straight forward (make sure it is JDK not JRE!) and since your SDK is inside a win32 folder make sure it is the 32bit JDK. I'll test it on windows again and update my tutorial at https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#windows + add a post here. Otherwise you could join tislack.org and ask in the #helpme channel again.

Comment: I am starting to suspect that my java setup is correct but my jdk directory itself was bad.  I had an issue with jdks downloaded by appcelerator.  A colleague suggested that I let android studio do the downloading.  I pointed them to the same jdk folder and I suspect that at some point they started tripping over each other when I was trying to get various versions of android to work (a different headache).  I noticed this morning that appcelerator was complaining that it couldn't find any jdks even though the directory was present.  I am currently downloading fresh jdks in a new directory.

Comment: don't mix it up with Android SDKs. Normally you use Android Studio to download sdk/ndk and not the Java JDK (since that is from Oracle)

Comment: So I split out the directories so that they don't trip over each other.  When in the appcelerator studio client I no longer see sdk errors.  However, I still get the original error when I try to run the simple app in an emulator.  Do I need android NDK path?  I tried to point it to the ndk folder in the jdk downloaded by visual studio (as per appcelerator directions) but it complained that ndk-build folder was missing.

Comment: ndk is just needed for modules. Why do you have an NDK folder inside the JDK :) ? You download NDK as a ZIP or with Android Studio. As mentioned earlier `appc ti config android` has a ndkPath. It is something seperate and has nothing todo with JDK here.

Comment: Android studio put the ndk folder inside of it's jdk folder.  I was following this doc:  https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+the+Android+NDK

Either way, I don't think that's my problem as I am pretty sure that this field was blank when this was working last week.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `The NDK is not required to build, run, or distribute apps using the Titanium SDK.` I'll try it in windows later on. It is very confusing since you even mentioning `visual studio` at one point :-D Can you compile the app via CLI (command mentioned above)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Just to be clear, I was trying to start working on titanium apps in VS code because I hated the appcelerator studio client.  That's when the problems started.  I have since hopped back over to the Appcelerator Studio client and I am trying to fix the issue there because I can reproduce it there.  

I followed the build command mentioned earlier and got the same errors.  When I echo %java_home% I get this in return:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251.

Comment: here is my `appc info`: https://gist.github.com/m1ga/ac0a9da7b9bfae362d50490106582362 please update your post with your current `appc info` and run `javac -version` as seen in line 47 + run the commands at the bottom to create a new app and post the output of that if there is an error

Comment: Thanks!  I updated the post with the info about an hour ago.  

I followed your steps and got the same jdk error on the build step.  javac - version results in javac 1.8.0_251.

Comment: since it doesn't find it automatically you could try to set https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+CLI+Options#TitaniumCLIOptions-java.home `appc ti config java.home /path/to/jdk` and try it again

Comment: Tried that as well.  One the command line I used appc to set java.home.  It said it was successful so I closed out of the command prompt and then re-opened.  Same error when issuing build command on the new app I created an hour ago.

Comment: I think this all boils down to one thing:  when I run app -info it shows that there is no jdk selected.   When I try to set it in environment variables or via command line it still doesn't select it.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Ubuntu!

Comment: @dazza5000: https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#ubuntu I'm using Fedora myself but the setup is very similar. You can even use openjdk

Comment: this fixed it for me on ubuntu: I was able to get this working on Ubuntu by removing every jdk installation through synaptic and then installing a jdk using sudo apt install default-jdk